# Bootstrap 3: Column Ordering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these three columns.
In a Medium screen, It should go like: Column A (col-md-6) will be at the top, Column B (col-md-6) beside Column A,and Column C (col-md-12) underneath Column A and B.

Like so:

[image: planned structure]

I'm having a problem with coming up into this kind of ordering.
Here's my current code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="content1 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        6-Col-[X-Small] A
      </div>

      <div class="content3 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        12-Col-[Medium] C
      </div>

      <div class="content2 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        6-Col-[X-Small] B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this at the moment:
[image: current code]

I checked out the Bootstrap Docs and used column pushing/pulling.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="content1 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        6-Col-[X-Small] A
      </div>

      <div class="content3 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-push-6">
        12-Col-[Medium] C
      </div>

      <div class="content2 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-12">
        6-Col-[X-Small] B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this method seems to mess up the layout.

[image: messed up layout]

Did I miss something in my code? It doesn't go as I intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest your `row` classes within each other like so:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="content1 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        6-Col-[X-Small] A
        <div class="row">
           <div class="content3 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
             12-Col-[Medium] C
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content2 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        6-Col-[X-Small] B
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and then set a custom media query on the nested `.content3` element

```
@media(min-width: 992px){
    .content3{
        width: calc(100% * 2);
    }
}
```

The above uses the same width break point as Bootstrap's `.col-md-12`.  At that threshold, the width of `.content3` becomes twice that of it's nesting DIV.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ48R/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="content1 col-md-6">
                    6-Col-[X-Small] A
                    </div>
                    <div class="content2 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    6-Col-[X-Small] B
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="content3 col-xs-12 ">
                    12-Col-[Medium] C
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You missed the fact the column B must fall *below* column C on xs

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to duplicate some of your content(either column b or c) and add `visible-xs` and `hidden-xs` to the appropriate version of content. Initially, I didn't like the idea of duplicating the content, but then realized it made sense for optimization as I could load bigger/smaller photo depending on device.

[See my previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718339/change-order-of-divs-with-push-pull-column-in-bootstrap), with a great example [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/h6C3e/) by @paulalexandru.

Here is the setup with **your** example content, and a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unr6u/)**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="content1 col-md-6 purple">
        6-Col-[X-Small] A
      </div>

      <div class="content3 col-md-12 visible-xs blue">
        12-Col-[Medium] C
      </div>

      <div class="content2 col-md-6 red">
        6-Col-[X-Small] B
      </div>

      <div class="content3 col-md-12 hidden-xs green">
        12-Col-[X-Small] C V2
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: The `blue, red, green, purple` classes are for easier visibility of what's going on in the example.

Also, if you've got content that is col-xs-12 and want it to also be col-12 at bigger screens, it will happen automatically. Don't specify `col-xs-12 and col-md-12` If you do it seems to throw off the height (in this example anyways - *why* is a little unclear to me, but that's beside the point).

> *Patient:* "It hurts when I do this..?" *Dr:* "Don't do that." :)

Also also, you'll notice a 2nd jump in layout at `sm`, because that's what lives between xs and md. Assuming you don't want that, you should replace `col-md-*` with `col-sm-*` in your example. Unless that's behaviour you want.