# How can I reorder Boostrap cols across across two rows and only for col-sm?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am having trouble ordering columns using Bootstrap 3. I have four divs of form fields that are ordered alphabetically. Currently, they appear correctly in xs (col-xs-12) as one column of four divs stacked on top of each other:

```
1 a
2 ↓
3 ↓
4 z
```

In md and lg, I have them as four divs in a row (col-md-3) which also works great:

```
1 2 3 4
a e k s
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
d j r z
```

The problem arises with sm where I would like to have two columns (col-sm-6) next to each other. In this instance, I would like to swap the second and third divs. Currently, I get this:

```
1   2     a→j

3   4     k→z
```

But I would like to get this:

```
1   3     a   k
          ↓   ↓
2   4     j   z
```

The reason I want to do this swap is to maintain the alphabetic ordering going top to bottom in one column, then top to bottom in the second.

I have tried using push/pull to no avail - it seems as though it does not work to push things over onto another line or pull them up... I also read [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797874/bootstrap-3-column-ordering) where the suggested answer was nested columns - but I am not sure how I could use that here since, in the xs view I want all of the divs to be on top of each other. Another respondent to that question proposes using hidden/visible which initially I thought might work but, since these are form fields, I don't want to have duplicate fields where potentially a user's already answered questions disappear on a resizing of their screen, to be replaced with the same fields that now appear to them to be unanswered...

I had a nifty picture prepared to illustrate my problem but am a new user so wasn't able to post it - I hope I was able to make myself clear. Also, if this question has already been answered elsewhere and I missed it, please let me know. Thank you in advance for any insight and/or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nesting is the best approach..

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              1
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              2
              </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              3
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              4
              </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/lAPR06iMI5

Comment: Thank you, @Skelly - very helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Check this article [Reorder CSS Columns Using Bootstrap](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap) by Chris Sevilleja.

I think that's what you are looking for.

```
<div class="container text-center">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-3">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-3">3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">4</div>
</div>
```