# How do i split content within a column into an adjacent column on mobile & tablet

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am using bootstrap3 and i am trying to move content from one column to another when using  mobile & tablet. I have to place it inside another column because i am specifically placing it under a heading / image in the adjacent column and the rest at the bottom for a better mobile experience. The page is fully coded and i am trying to improve the mobile experience.

The attached image should explain what i am trying to achieve visually.
link:  [Visual look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4sNC.jpg)

My current plan is to duplicate the content and only show it on the mobile & tablet view, whilst hide the original column on mobile & tablet. I am just wondering if this will start to get too page heavy, especially for mobile? (its my understanding that all content is still loaded even when using @media?)

Am i approaching this correctly?

Col-1 and Col-2 as per the image are technically not "col" but they are there on larger screens. This is the basic structure as is for the two right col of the picture i am trying to fix for mobile.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class=col-md-8>
   All of the content from col-3 as per image
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4>
   All of the content from col-4 as per the image
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: might be the right approach, but can better tell if you share your code.

Comment: Hey Shawn, i think it might be the only option without having to recode or change the design & layout. I could probably re-do the code and have separate rows for the whole page, but it doesn't make sense and will take too long.

Comment: Yeah. hidden-xs is simple and works. It solved my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718339/change-order-of-divs-with-push-pull-column-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple classes to give different behavior depending on screen size.

The [grid section of Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) help gives more details, but in your case:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
   All of the content from col-3 as per image
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
   All of the content from col-4 as per the image
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, yes everything has been coded as you have mentioned and scaled down. I just put the basic structure there as an example. I think @media with duplicate content is the only way to basically move content from one column to the next. As i am basically breaking down the last column into separate sections and moving them to another column in a different position.